# Black screen of death on ubuntu, need the chrome passwords anyway to get them back?

Tags: google-chrome, google

I have a dell inspiron notebook with ubuntu on it, absolutly love it and use it as a work laptop. Everytime my harddrive fails i just grab an old 30gig xbox hdd. Well a few days ago i ended up with the black screen after boot logo, something to do with intel graphics drivers updatinf and crashing the boot kernal. I spent a good 5 hours going through all the walkthroughs and gave up. I have only one thing of value on that hdd, and thats my google chrome passwords.

Is there a way i can import those onto my fresh install? Or am i sol?

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem with the black screen and a way i found to boot is change the option of boot in the grub for another kernel in advanced options (not recovery mode nor network)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** The already existing duplicate is a better match for OPs answer than yours, but don't be desperate: if you're a native Enlish speaker: we have tons of spelling and grammar errors here on the site: click the small grey `edit` link on the bottom if you see any and if you're not: every now and then someone posts in their native language and if it's identical to yours, edit and translate, please?  *Thank you!*

Comment: Ya i have tried all my kernals, im pretty sure my boot file is full and ive spent hours on this forum trying to solve that and gave up :(